# Time series regression with stationary and integrated variables using local projections

Tags: time-series, least-squares, econometrics, cointegration, unit-root

I am estimating structural impulse response functions of a five-variable model (say $x_1$, ... , $x_5$) using
[Jorda's local projection method](https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/0002828053828518) and an external shock series.

The local projections are an alternative to the VAR(p).
The method basically boils down to estimating for every variable $y \in \{x_1, \dots x_5 \}$ and for every horizon $h \in \{0, \dots, H\}$ the following linear regression.

$y_{t+h} = \alpha_0^h + \sum_{i = 1}^p\alpha_1^h x_{1,t-i} + \sum_{i = 1}^p\alpha_2^h x_{2,t-i} + \sum_{i = 1}^p\alpha_3^h x_{3,t-i} + \sum_{i = 1}^p\alpha_4^h x_{4,t-i} + \sum_{i = 1}^p\alpha_5^h x_{5,t-i} + \beta^h shock_t+ u_t.$

And the impulse response function is $\{\beta^h\}_{h=0}^H$.

***Note: I am only interested in the consistent estimation of $\beta^h$. I don't care about the other parameters.***

The problem is that on a couple of the data sets I have one or more $I(1)$ variables.

I think that I have figured out what to do in the case where there is only one $I(1)$ variable:

When this variable -say $x_1$ is on the left hand side of the equation -
$x_{1, t+h} = \alpha_0^h + \sum_{i = 1}^p\alpha_1^h x_{1,t-i} + \sum_{i = 1}^p\alpha_2^h x_{2,t-i} + \sum_{i = 1}^p\alpha_3^h x_{3,t-i} + \sum_{i = 1}^p\alpha_4^h x_{4,t-i} + \sum_{i = 1}^p\alpha_5^h x_{5,t-i} + \beta^h shock_t+ u_t.$

the regression is balanced as $E(x_{1, t+h} - x_{1, t-i}) = 0$.

I also think that adding a time trend when a stationary variable is on the right hand side solves the problem with the stochastic trend of $x_1$ although I have a harder time showing this.

I however don't know what to do when there are more I(1) variables in the system. Both in the case with cointegration and in the case without cointegration among the I(1)-variables.

I don't feel like differencing some of the trending variables. For example - the interest rate, as I would have a hard time interpreting the results.